# TypeScript can't tell if the returned value of an async function is already resolved

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

The title may not sound very clear, so here is a snippet of code.

```
class UserService {
    static async findNumber(): number {
        return await new Promise<number>((res) => setTimeout(() => res(1)}, 1000));
    }
}
```

The code above results in `Type 'number' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.ts(1055)`.

The error will be gone if I change the return type of the function into `Promise<number>`. However, this seems odd, because the `Promise` is supposed to be resolved before the function returns a number.

Does this mean that TypeScript can't tell if the returned value of an async function is already resolved?

Comment: The moment you declare a function *async* it will always, no matter what, return a promise. Even `const answer = async () => 42;` would return a promise. So the idea of an *already resolved* is not valid.

Comment: In addition, you don't need to use `async/await` all the time if you're using `Promise` directly. A good practice would be to use `async/await` when consuming functions or methods that already use the `Promise` API. [Similar to this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOBlZA3AlsB0DeAUNMdBAC5hnbQBmmAdgCYByArgLYBGyAFAJT4iJYUgRlWSetHoIA7tAAKSAPbtMiADz0O3JAD4eoiMpDpcAXj2kxAFUzsEy1mR79ol6EZNmeARj4ANNC+AAxhfHwA3ELEAL4EsUA)

Comment: @Yoshi That's the answer, apparently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your returned type should be `Promise<number>`, not number

```
async function findNumber(): Promise<number> {
  return new Promise();
}
```

cause it returns a promise, not a number value